# CUDA: optimize latency due to iterative process

Tags: optimization, cuda, fft, latency

I have an iterative computation that involves a Fourier transform in each iteration.

in high level it looks like this:

```
// executed in host , calling functions that run on the device
B = image
L = 100
while(L--) {
    A = FFT_2D(B)
    A = SOME_PER_PIXEL_CALCULATION(A)
    B = INVERSE_FFT_2D(A)
    B = SOME_PER_PIXEL_CALCULATION(B)
}
```

I am using "cufft" library to do the transforms.

now the problem is that I am always working  with global memory,

basically if there was a way of doing some of the work with shared memory it would be great,

but it seems like using FFT won't allow me to bypass this, given "cufft" library functions can only be called from the host, and stores input and output in global memory.

how should I tackle this?

thanks.

---

EDIT:

since there IS a data dependency. it would seem like I can't do much but optimize the 'per pixel' calculations...

the bottleneck is still due to the fact that the kernels pass the data via global memory .which seems unavoidable in this case.

so basically the fact that I have to do the transform an it's inverse is what keeps me from sharing intermidiate computation data.

currently I am exploring ways of doing most of the calculation in the frequency space.
( more of a math problem )

so does anyone has a good idea on how to [approximate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271031/need-numerical-approximation-for-fouriermax0-fx-given-fourierfx) F{max(0,f(x,y))} given F{f(x,y)} ?

---

EDIT:

note that f(x,y) is in the time domain, and therefore is real valued,

f(x,y) is also processed before calculating pointwise max(0,f(x,y)), so it is indeed possible for negetiv values to appear.

Comment: You are saying that A and B are on global memory?

Comment: Yes, mainly because "cufft" library only allowes to operate on global memory.

Comment: Assume that the cufft calls (FFT_2D, INVERSE_FFT_2D) are well-written and will make best use of shared memory if possible.  That means you want to focus your attention on SOME_PER_PIXEL_CALCULATION routines.  Just because the image or it's transform is stored in global memory doesn't mean that shared memory can't be used to good effect.  But without knowing what your per-pixel functions are doing, there's not much else that can be said.  You wouldn't be able to put the entire image in shared memory anyway unless it's smaller than about 48K bytes.

Comment: How are you comparing 0 to a complex number ?

Comment: I was trying to simplify the calculation I will edit the post.

Comment: @BenMatok I have posted some comments on your mathematical problem at [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271031/need-numerical-approximation-for-fouriermax0-fx-y-given-fourierfx-y/271778#271778). I hope they will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the FFT/IFFT, I think you are wrongly assuming that the CUFFT routine does not internally use shared memory. Typical algorithms for FFT calculations split the entire FFT into smaller ones fitting one thread block and so probably they already internally exploit shared memory, see for example the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/131400/FftGpuSC08.pdf).

Concerning the PER_PIXEL_CALCULATIONS, shared memory is typically used to make threads within a thread block cooperate each other. My question is: are the PER_PIXEL_CALCULATIONS independent each other? If so, perhaps thread cooperation is not needed and you would not need shared memory either and arrange the calculations by using only registers.

Anyway, to be more specific on the latter point, you should provide more information on what you actually need (by editing your original post). Is your code related to an implementation of the Gerchberg-Saxton algorithm?